# how to get value that is given in select tags from one jsp page to another jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jasper-reports

Actually if i select an option like "company" and click on "submit" it will go to "view2.jsp" and using the option which i selected in "view1.jsp" i will display only that "company" data into either PDF,DOC,XLS,XLSX. Here i am using jasper reports in order to display data into PDF or DOC or XLS or XLSX.
What i did was as follows

view1.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="view2.jsp">
<select name="category">
<option value='company'>company</option>
<option value='institution'>institution</option>
<option value='hospital'>hospital</option>
<option value='Others'>Others</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' value="Given">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

view2.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function setAction(nPage){

        document.forms[0].action = nPage;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
String name;
name = request.getParameter("category");
%>
<form>
<select value="name" onchange="setAction(this.value)">
<option value=''> Make a selection </option>
<option value='PDF2.jsp'> PDF</option>
<option value='XLS2.jsp'> XLS </option>
<option value='DOC.jsp'> DOC </option>
<option value='XLSX2.jsp'> XLSX </option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp
<input type='submit' value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem i am facing is that i am not getting the option value that i selected in view1.jsp to view2.jsp and i am not getting the option data into PDF and DOC and XLS and XLSX.

Comment: You are getting it (into the `String name` variable), but not using it anywhere in the `view2.jsp`.

Comment: can you write the code of how to use it because i have to submit the code by tomorrow.Please help me

Comment: It depends on how do you want to use it, but the standard way would be to use EL: `${name}`. Or you can use it the "scriptlet way": `<%= name %>` - although I wouldn't recommend it. Anyway, you should read (and do) some tutorial first, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html

Answer (score 1):

`request.getParameter("category");` this is returning you the drop down value which you selected in view1 which you are storing in `name`.

You can simply display it on view2.jsp as
`You have chosen <%= name %>`on page name(view1.jsp).

Comment: Can you write the full code once?? it would be helpful to me